# Find all product that contain terms with %keywords% in WP_Query

Tags: wp-query, woocommerce-offtopic, tax-query

I want to use WP_Query to find all product terms entered in the input field.
Here is my WP_Query code.

```
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$args = array(
    'post_type'         => 'product',
    'product_cat'       => 'construction',
    'posts_per_page'    => 12,
    'paged'             => $paged,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy'  => 'pa_reference-p-no',
            'field'     => 'slug',
            'terms'     => $input_search_txt
        )
    );
);

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
```

'**$input_search_txt**' is the text entered in the input field.
I want to find all products that contain this text in 'pa_reference-p-no'.
**For example, if I search for '123', I want to find products with terms '12345' or '123456'.**

But now I can only see the product with the term '123'.

I want someone to help me.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, `tax_query` does not have a `compare` match modifier like `meta_query`, allowing for wildcard searches with the 'LIKE' operator.  So you need to have a different approach.  I can think of 2 ways to solve this problem,

1) Use the global [$wpdb](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) object to search for all the terms that match your text search and then use those term ids to add an [operator](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) match modifier to your current query, [EDIT: added a debug line, make sure you [enable WP_DEBUG]](https://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG)

```
    global $wpdb; 
    $term_ids = $wpdb->get_results( 
        "
        SELECT {$wpdb->terms}.term_id 
        FROM {$wpdb->terms}, {$wpdb->term_taxonomy}
        WHERE {$wpdb->terms}.term_id =  {$wpdb->term_taxonomy}.term_id
            AND {$wpdb->term_taxonomy}.taxonomy LIKE 'pa_reference-p-no'
            AND {$wpdb->terms}.slug LIKE '%{$input_search_txt}%'
        ",
        ARRAY_N
    );
    //you can debug your term id results at this point by printing them in your log file, make sure WP_DEBUG is set to true in your wp_config.php file.
    error_log('TERM IDS:'.print_r($term_ids,true)); //should be an array of term ids.
    $args = array(
        'post_type'         => 'product',
        'product_cat'       => 'construction',
        'posts_per_page'    => 12,
        'paged'             => $paged,
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy'  => 'pa_reference-p-no',
                'terms'     => $term_ids,
                'operator'  => 'IN'
            )
        );
    );

    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
```

2) the second method would be to add a custom sql condition to your query using the [query filter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Filters) [posts_where](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_where) filter.  So you would simplify your query to search for only the 'product' posts and then modify the taxonomy condition using,

```
        add_filter( 'posts_where' , 'posts_where', 10,2 );

        function posts_where( $where , $query) {

            if( 'product' == $query->query_vars['post_type'] && !$query->is_main_query() && !$query->is_admin() ) {
                global $wpdb;

                if ( isset( $_POST['input_search_txt'] ) && !empty( $_POST['input_search_txt'] ) ) {

                   $where .= 
                   " 
                     AND {$wpdb->terms}.term_id =  {$wpdb->term_taxonomy}.term_id
                     AND {$wpdb->term_taxonomy}.taxonomy LIKE 'pa_reference-p-no'
                     AND {$wpdb->terms}.slug LIKE '%{$_POST['input_search_txt'];}%'
                 ";
                }
            }
            return $where;
        }
```

Both of these solution should work, although I haven't tested them.  The first one is easier to debug, and only target your current query.  The second solution is more efficient as it makes 1 less hit on your DB, however keeping in mind that if you don't filter the `$query` in the initial condition, you can end up having other custom queries being affected and these can be very difficult to debug.

Let me know in the comments below if you have any problems understanding it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, the first method causes an error.

`WordPress database error: [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '}.term_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_id AND wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy LIKE 'pa' at line 3]
SELECT term_id FROM wp_terms WHERE (wp_terms}.term_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_id AND wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy LIKE 'pa_reference-p-no' AND wp_terms.slug LIKE '%3996%'`

Comment: I also tested the second method.
; << causes an error in this part. 
`AND {$wpdb->terms}.slug LIKE '%{$_POST['input_search_txt'];}%'`
I removed it, but I did not get the results I wanted.

Comment: Dear @Mike, apologies I realised there was a typo in my SQL query which I have now fixed in the 1st method.  I have also added a debug line for you to validate the initial term ids returned.  Can you have another go with the first method and see if you get any results.

Comment: as for the 2nd method this is more tricky to debug as it is possible that the conditional statements are not being passed, it all depends on where you are running the query.  If I get a moment, I will test the 2nd method on my local machine and come back here to correct it.  For  now let's see if u can get your problem fixed with the 1st method as that's easier to debug